# T-SQL (Looking for a way to find new records added under new date range)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a single table that compiles records and each record has a data associated with the record. For instance my most recent data range is `2014-2-8` my second data range is `2014-1-6`, this query is going to be placed in a report so I would like to have the code dynamic.

I can figure out the max date using

```
select max((alias.date)) 
from table as alias1 
where alias.date = alias1.date
```

My end game is to write a select with `id`, `productname`, `date`, whatever new product is in the most recent data range will pull in the query.

Essentially any product associated with max date will compare against the second to max date (sorry stupid I know) and produce those products.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share some more code/schema? What you've tried so far? What is *alias1* in your query?

Comment: My table has 3 columns.  ProductId, Product and Date.  When ever I set up an ETL I always build out a varchar date column to give me reference to my columns.  So essentially what I am trying to do it compare product with max date against product 1 less than max date.  I can write pieces like  WHERE r.PDate = (SELECT MAX((r1.PDate)) from [dbo].[RawData] as r1 where r.PDate = r1.PDate) to get max range, but it's not coming together for me.  I was thinking maybe a Union between select max data and select < max, but that will pull in additional date ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the row with the highest date:

```
MSSQL: select top 1 * from table order by datefield desc
MySQL: select * from table order by datefield desc limit 1
```

Comment: @thepirat000    `WITH Reportdate_CTE (PublicationName, PubID, ReportDate)
AS
(
  SELECT PublicationName, PubID, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By PubID ORDER BY ReportDate Asc)) as ReportDate1
  FROM [Client].[TSA_RawData] as r

)
SELECT PublicationName, PubID, ReportDate
FROM ReportDate_CTE as CTE
GROUP BY PublicationName, ReportDate, PubID
ORDER BY ReportDate Desc`

Comment: Essentially I have 3 columns what is listed above.  Every time I load a new set of records these records have the date that I loaded them.  For instance 61,000 records could of be loaded today which would all have todays date next to them for instance.  PubID 2000, PubName Magazine, and Date 2014-3-7 (Date Datatype).  I am trying to essentially pull all records with max data and max date -1.  Then compare the publication names verse each other with a <>.  I just started using CTE's and Row Number so I am struggling still.  THanks for any help!

Comment: if you want 2 rows, use `top 2`

Comment: I am looking to pull back all rows with max date and max date -1 Not just the top two rows.

Comment: That's why you sort by the datefield with descending sort.  Did you not even try the query in my answer at all?  If you sort by the date field in descending order, and then pull the top 2 rows, what will that be?  That will be the row with max date and the row with the next highest date.

Comment: @ Developerwjk I did and it pulled back the two rows both of which were the same date.  When I bulk load the data in this table I assign a primary key and a reportdate column which is the day the data is uploaded.  Multiple rows have the same date next to them.  I get the top two rows when I drop your query.

Comment: You need to improve your database. Probably as you have it setup, there is no solution to your problem.  Or rather, considering how your data is stored, your request doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the updates I really appreciate it.  It helped out a lot!